# SQL find certain names/title in table with matching strings but different order

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains data from manual input. Everytime a user creates a “rule” in the system and chooses a name for it, it is saved like that. So two rules can mean the same, and do the same, but have slightly different names. Example:

Rule 1:
Cars sold in US, EU and JP

Rule 2:
Cars sold in EU, JP and US

Rule 3:
Cars sold in EU, US, JP, MX and GE

What I have to do is find certain patterns within these thousands of rules. Like this:
Find Cars that have been sold in US, EU and JP.

Now the result should show rule 1 and rule 2. Both contain the same info in their names, just in a different order. Rule 3 contains these info too, but also other countries like MX and GE so it should not taken into account.

So far I have an SQL which finds rule 1 and rule 2 but also rule 3, and I can’t figure out how to tell that machine that I don’t want any other rules that contain my strings in their name with other info too.

```
select RULE_NUM, RULE_NAME from TB_RULE 
where RULE_NAME like '% Cars sold in%'
and RULE_NAME like '%US%'
and RULE_NAME like '%EU%'
and RULE_NAME like '%JP%'
```

Thanks a lot. Appreciate it!!

Comment: Can you add how the rules are defined/entered in their actual table?

Comment: I think you are going to need to  create a list of unique country codes in an IN clause, but hard to know without seeing the structure of the rules. Ideally, you would have application logic that would prevent creating different rules that only differ in order, but that is another matter.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using sybase. i was hoping to avoid naming all possible country codes, because this is just one example. there are other codes as well

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to convert the `Rule_Name` into a set of flags, as a first step, otherwise your where clause is just gonna be a massive set of likes and brackets:)

i.e.

```
select Rule_Name
   , CarsSoldFlag = case when Rule_Name like '%Cars sold in%' then 1 else 0 end
   , InUSFlag = case when Rule_Name like %US% then 1 else 0 end
   , InJPFlag = case when Rule_Name like %JP% then 1 else 0 end
   ...etc
```

Once you've broken down the rules into their component bits, the querying should become easier.

Comment: thanks. but where would I go from there with flags? I guess I need to check for relevant flags = 1?

Comment: how would I use these flags in the where clause? If I type InUSFlag = 0 I'll get an error....thanks :)